# Target Angular mat-checkbox nested dinamically created element

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a series of checkboxes that I create using `mat-checkbox`, with it respective **Select all** one. What I need is to target that specific (and first) checkbox and hide it. Only the checkbox, not the label or any other element within `mat-checkbox`.
My checkboxes are default ones, so an example would be something like this:

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-all-checkbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

After the elements are created, you have a structure that looks like this:

```
  <mat-checkbox _ngcontent-ici-c72="" class="mat-checkbox mat-accent ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched"
    ng-reflect-model="false" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" d="mat-checkbox-1">
    <label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="mat-checkbox-1-input">
      <div class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-checkbox-1-input" tabindex="0"
          aria-checked="false">
        <div matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-checkbox-ripple mat-focus-indicator"
          ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLLabelElement]" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-radius="20"
          ng-reflect-centered="true" ng-reflect-animation="[object Object]">
          <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mat-checkbox-frame"></div>
        <div class="mat-checkbox-background"><svg version="1.1" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xml:space="preserve" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark">
            <path fill="none" stroke="white" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path"></path>
          </svg>
          <div class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display: none;">&nbsp;
        </span>Select All</span>
    </label>
  </mat-checkbox>
```

Everything created after the page is loaded by Angular, except the `span` element that contains **Select All**.
I need to target only the first element that contains the class `mat-checkbox-inner-container`
So far, if I try via CSS, all elements with that class are hidden, i.e. all checkboxes, not only the first one.
I've also tried to create a class in my CSS and add it via TS, with no positive result. This is the snippet for that:

```
checkHider():void {
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("mat-checkbox-inner-container")[0];
    elem.classList.add("hider");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the element inside the `ngOnInit` function, and it worked.
This is the snippet. *Note that the position is only specific to my case.*

```
let elem = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[6];
elem.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
```